# How do I change Windows Server 2016 DNS Settings?

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, windows-server-2016

I just want to change the DNS server that my windows 2016 server is pointing to, but I can't seem to find this basic information.

All that is available online in any searches is how to make my Windows 2016 Server a new DNS server, which I don't want it to do.

I just need it to point to an existing DNS server. Anyone know how to do this?  I think it's very basic but it's another one of those very basic things that seems impossible to find.

Answer (score 4):

You change it (and any Windows server) in the NIC settings.

See [here](https://www.petri.com/configuring-dns-server-addresses-for-network-adapter) for more information/citation.

Log in to -the server- with an administrator account. To change the IP address and DNS server settings for a network adapter using the GUI:

On the desktop, right-click the network icon in the bottom right of the Task Bar and select Open Network and Sharing Center from the menu.

In the Network and Sharing Center, click Change adapter settings.

Right-click the relevant network adapter in the Network Connections window and select Properties from the menu.

In the adapter’s Properties window, select Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4) and click Properties.

Enter the required IP address and DNS server settings and then click OK.
Click Close in the adapter’s Properties window.

Comment: Ahh, so just like in regular windows.  I thought it would be different for Server 2016. Thanks! :D

Comment: +1 to answer a FAQ question

Answer (score 1):

You can easily change the DNS server settings using control panel:

1.Go to Control Panel.

2.Click on Network and Internet.

3.Network and sharing

4.Click Change adapter settings options in the left pane.

5.Click the network interface connected to the internet

6.Select Properties option.

7.Select the Internet Protocol version 4 (TCP/IPv4)

8.Click Properties.

9.Click the Use the following DNS Server address option.

10. Type your preferred and alternate DNS address.

and that's all.

if you want to know more about check this [Windows DNS Configuration](https://windowsmaximizer.com/blog/dns-server/).